# Change elements of a SVG (lines, circles, squares) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to create a SVG picture with circles and rectangles connected through lines (some sort of decision tree). An algorithm will analyze some data and then will successively change the color of the circle stroke, then of line and finally the stroke of the rectangle (there will be more circles/line/rectangles linked together). It needs to be done with Javascript. Below is a piece of code as example. Any suggestions on how to change successively the color of the circle stroke, line and rectangle with Javascript? Once the color is set it must stay until the user aborts the procedure. Thank you.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <style>
      svg#chart {
        background: lightgray;
      }
      #chart line 
      #chart circle 
      #chart rect 
    </style>
    <svg width="300" height="425">
      <line x1="80" y1="104" x2="80" y2="192" style="stroke:orange;stroke- 
     width:30"></line>
      <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="40" style="stroke:yellow;stroke- 
    width:28;fill:green"></circle>
      <rect x="50" y="202" width="150" height="150" 
     style="stroke:#282828;stroke-width:20;fill:magenta"</rect>
    </svg>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please share screenshot of structure you are looking for

Comment: Tutorials for this are numerous and this shows no attempt on your own, come on back after a quick trip to the search engine of your choice and you run into trouble. Cheers!